# Meter and rhythm in Poetry

Tags: british-english, poetry, linguistics, literature, meter

Why is poetry called a 'literature in metrical form' or 'a composition forming rhythmic lines'?

[image: I found this image on Google while searching the definition of poetry]

Comment: Is this a question about etymology? Otherwise I'm not sure what answer you're looking for.

Comment: Because poetry is something which has a particular metre and rhythm.

Comment: As Bob Dylan rather profoundly illustrated, poetry is what you can get away with calling poetry.

Comment: Do I need ask this question in Literature section?

Comment: If so, I will delete it

Comment: @yubraj Might do better in Literature, or Writing, as poetry seems to be any string of words that does something to your mental state that mere words alone are not able of accomplishing. There's an odd power in poesy, and strict grammarian examination is *not* going to get to the bottom of it.

Answer (score 1):

The definition you've cited is wrong. [Britannica](https://www.britannica.com/art/poetry) defines poetry as

> "literature that evokes a concentrated imaginative awareness of
>   experience or a specific emotional response through language chosen
>   and arranged for its meaning, sound, and rhythm".

A work in metrical form *may* be poetry, but metre or rhythm is not necessary for a work to be regarded as poetry.